# Convert Time to Another Timezone with Considering Daylight Time Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert specific time to my local timezone that is **Asia/Tehran** with this code:

```
var date = new Date("9/9/2021 17:30 UTC +1").toLocaleString('en-US', {
        "timeZone": "Asia/Tehran"
})
```

Based on this link https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converter.html?iso=20211009T163000&p1=3903&p2=246 I should get **20:00** time. But I'm getting **21:00**.
I know this is because of daylight times in Iran, But how can I consider daylight times when I want to use the JavaScript `toLocaleString` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the link, you have the month October, whereas in your code, you have September .

Comment: Thanks for answering! But now I have another question, I used new Date().getMonth() to get the month and it is returning number 9 which is September. How can I solve this?

Comment: .getMonth() returns a 0 based value. Which means January is 0, February is 1 and so on. Hence, you can just add 1 to Date().getMonth().

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth